# php - array_fill negative indices

Tags: php

When using `php` [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) and negative indices, why does `php` only fill the first negative indice and then jump to 0.

For example:

`array_fill(-4,4,10)` should fill `-4, -3, -2, -1` and `0` but it does `-4, 0, 1, 2, 3`

The manual does state this behaviour but not why.

Can anyone say why this is?

Comment: "It's not a bug, it's a feature".

Comment: Unless you can find the guy who implemented it I don't think the question *"why they did it"* is really answerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source for PHP, I can see exactly why they did this!

What they do is create the first entry in the array. In PHP, it looks like:

```
$a = array(-4 => 10);
```

Then, they add each new entry like this:

```
$count--;
while ($count--) {
  $a[] = 10;
}
```

If you do this exact same thing yourself, you'll see the exact same behavior. A super short PHP script demonstrates this:

```
<?php
    $a = array(-4 => "Apple");
    $a[] = "Banana";
    print_r($a);
?>
```

The result: `Array ( [-4] => Apple [0] => Banana )`

**NOTE**
Yes, I did put in PHP instead of the C source they used, since a PHP programmer can understand that a lot better than the raw source. It's approximately the same effect, however, since they ARE using the PHP functions to generate the results...

Comment: Well, that is the how I suppose. The why, in my best guess, is due to laziness on their part. It may be one of those dogmatic programming concepts that negative indices in an array are bad, but they don't say in comments or anything...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because it's stated in the doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php

> If start_index is negative, the first index of the returned array will be start_index and the following indices will start from zero (see example).

Comment: The poster has asked for thoughts on why this behaviour is provided, as the manual page does not elaborate.

Comment: so you think we should open php sources, look at this behaviour coded and try to guess why it's so looking at other related code pieces? I can't imagine any other way of explaining this thing

Comment: That's what he's asking. If you don't think the question belongs on SO, flag it as inappropriate and let a moderator decide.

Comment: If the question contained this man quoted, I'd think so. Otherwise it's all your or anyone else's guesses (as well as the answers to the question unless they are based on analyzing php source)

Comment: argh, I should have read it attenticely, now I see the ref to man, my apologies

Comment: No problem, but you may be right about the question not being one that can be answered, so it may not belong here on SO.