# Array index vanishing with array_fill php

Tags: php, arrays

I went through the post -
    [php - array_fill negative indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604101/php-array-fill-negative-indices)

PHP sure doesn't say why it starts from 0 after the (-ive) start_index,but but but,if i try to `array_fill` from `-2` index for an array that already has `-1` and `0` index defined, the original array vanishes.

```
$a = array('-1'=>'harry','0'=>'alex');  
$a = array_fill(-2,4,'roger');

print_r($a);
```

output

```
Array ( [-2] => Roger [0] => Roger [1] => Roger [2] => Roger )
```

and `$a[-1]` is an undefined offset error. `$a[0]` is overwritten to roger.

Any explanations?? And working tips for future for similar situations..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `array_replace`

```
$a = array('-1'=>'harry','0'=>'alex');
$b = array_fill(-2, 4, 'Roger');

$c = array_replace($b, $a);
ksort($c);
print_r($c);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [-2] => Roger 
    [-1] => harry
    [0] => alex
    [1] => Roger 
    [2] => Roger 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`array_fill`](http://php.net/array_fill) manual:

> If start_index is negative, the first index of the returned array will be start_index and the following indices will start from zero (see example).

```
<?php
$a = array_fill(5, 6, 'banana');
$b = array_fill(-2, 4, 'pear');
print_r($a);
print_r($b);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [5]  => banana
    [6]  => banana
    [7]  => banana
    [8]  => banana
    [9]  => banana
    [10] => banana
)
Array
(
    [-2] => pear
    [0] => pear
    [1] => pear
    [2] => pear
)
```

So your output is correct. Next thing is that you are omitting first array. You should try with:

```
$a = array(-1 => 'harry', 0 => 'alex');
$a = array_merge(array_fill(-2, 4, 'roger'), $a);

ksort($a);
```

Comment: the final output will again have to be sorted if dealing with dynamic arrays

Comment: index association not maintained

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct method

```
$a = array('-1'=>'harry','0'=>'alex');  
$a = array_merge($a,array_fill(-2,4,'roger'));

print_r($a);
```

if arrk keys must be preserved

```
$a = array('-1'=>'harry','0'=>'alex');  
$b=array_fill('-2','4','roger');
    $a =  $a+ $b;

    print_r($a);
```

Comment: It will still overwrite `0` index.

Comment: Be carefull what are You merging over what... The order here is very important...

Comment: it still fails to maintain the order..i guess a round of sorting will have to be done.